# Authencation or Basic Authentication using GRequests

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, python-requests, basic-authentication

I want to make multiple [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) at the same time. I found python module that helps me to achieve that! but now I have a issue now I don't figure out how to handle simple  or basic authentication in each requests with this library.

Here is the code:

```
import grequests
urls = [
    'http://www.iroume.com',
    'http://itc.org',
]
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
```

Comment: You need to pass an `auth` argument in the `get` method as : `requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))`

Answer (score 2):

just use as request

```
rs = (grequests.get(u,auth=(username, password)) for u in urls)
```